# Disable a button when the keyboard is popped up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I got a UITextField, when you click on it there pops up a keyboard. I've added the UITextField using storyboard and now I want to disable a button when the keyboard pops up. How can I do this?

For disabling the button: `[self.howButton setEnabled:NO];` 
But where do I put this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add your keyboards stament to the `notifacticon` , when it show , then disable the button , when it hide , then enable the button

in the init to add the observer

```
- (void)init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

achieve the show and hide method

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide
{
    [self.howButton setEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow
{
    [self.howButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

finally remove the observer , when the class is dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I'm using ARC so I don't need to dealloc

Comment: When using NSNotificationCenter, does it slow down the app much?

Comment: @nonuma 1)although you use ARC, you also should remove the observer, 2)using NSNotificationCenter will not slow down the app much , only a very very very little , the slow down can be ignore

Answer (score 0):

Register for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

In the keyboardWillShow method disable your button.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

You can re-enable the button if required by registering for the above notification.